# openshift crash loop back-off with node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openshift

So I've been trying to create a server for dynamic web pages using Openshift, so I created a bare-bones node.js/Express template just for connecting to Index.html (to test the code) but when I try and run the code Openshift goes into a crash loop back-off.

Note: I'm new to Node.js and back-end development in general so please be thorough with your answers.

The Openshift error log:

```
Environment: 
    DEV_MODE=false
    NODE_ENV=production
    DEBUG_PORT=5858
Launching via npm...
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.9
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-693.15.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/npm" "run" "-d" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /opt/app-root/src/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/app-root/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/app-root/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
```

The github repo:
https://github.com/TrueAmbition001/TrueAmbition001.github.io

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node.js S2I builder requires the `package.json` and application code to be in the root directory of the repo, you have it in a sub directory. So the structure of your code doesn't match what is required.

For some details on the S2I builder for Node.js, see:

- https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/tree/master/8